# How to change the size of an iframe when device rotates?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, mobile

I have a iframe with the id "myframe" I want to change the height when the device rotates. this works like this

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){

$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  if(window.orientation == 0)
  {

     document.getElementById("myframe").height = 300;

  }
  else
  {
     document.getElementById("myframe").height = 500;

  }
});                   
});
</script>
```

but needs to work like this

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){

$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  if(window.orientation == 0)
  {
    var oldh = document.getElementById("myframe").height;

    var newh = parseInt(oldh) * 1.4;
    if(newh != ''){
     document.getElementById("myframe").height = newh;
     }
  }
  else
  {
    var oldh = document.getElementById("myframe").height;
    var newh = parseInt(oldh) / 1.4;

    if(newh != ''){
   document.getElementById("myframe").height = newh;
     }
  }
});                   
});
</script>
```

if i print the results for var newh it returns correctly but still will not run my function

Comment: Have you tried setting the height with css instead?
`document.getElementById('myframe').style.height = newh + 'px';`

Comment: Also, your calculation might well result in a float number. You have to do it like this: `var newh = parseInt(oldh / 1.4);`

Comment: You are right about the ParseInt format it works just fine.. Thank You :) if you put it as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation might well result in a float number. You have to do it like this:
    `var newh = parseInt(oldh / 1.4);`